# How to post multiple entries in REST

Tags: python, django, rest

I am building REST API which stores name, salary and expenses of people. How can I POST data of multiple people at the same time, like an array?

This is my serializers.py file

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Bucketlist


class BucketlistSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Bucketlist
        fields = ('id','name', 'date_created', 'salary','Expenditure')
        read_only_fields = ('date_created',)
```

This is my views.py file

[image: screenshot of views.py]

Comment: Can you post your view also?

Comment: @neverwalkaloner I have attached a link to my views.py file image since I can't post an image here because I just made this account. please have a look at it and help me out

Answer (score 1):

you should use (many=True) in the serializer while saving

```
data = BucketlistSerializer(data = your_post_array,many=True)
if data.is_valid():
   data.save()
```

add this to your view

```
    def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):

        if isinstance(kwargs.get('data', {}), list):
           kwargs['many'] = True
        return super("your view class name ", self).get_serializer(*args, **kwargs)
```

for function base view

```
@api_view(['GET','POST'])
   def somefunction(request):



    if request.method == 'POST':
       data = BucketlistSerializer(data = request.data["key_for_data"], many=True)
       if data.is_valid():
          data.save()
          return(data.data)
    return(data.errors)
```

post data will be : {"key_for_data":[{},{}]

Comment: do I need to add this code at the end of my serializers.py file, I am new to this stuff so can you explain a little bit

Comment: no no it will be in your view.py where save your data in class base view or function base view (where you call your serializer for saving )

Comment: ok I added that to the views.py file, now how do I post an array of entries or multiple entries at the same time. I am using postman to check the api.

Comment: as i updated the answer check with this update  you view  comment the previous  """data = BucketlistSerializer(data = your_post_array,many=True)
if data.is_valid():
   data.save()"""

Comment: [
    {
        "name": "manoj",
        "salary": 100000,
        "Expenditure": 50000
    },
    {
        "name": "sohan",
        "salary": 50000,
        "Expenditure": 10000
    }
]

Comment: I entered this in the postman post option, it shows the following error {
    "non_field_errors": [
        "Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got list."
    ]
}

Answer (score 1):

`Django` provides `many=True` attribute to pass while building queryset in your view. Please have a look on : 
[Multiple objects in serializer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-multiple-objects)